# Element type is invalid error come with react native and native base UI kit

Tags: react-native

Below error i'm facing with react native project

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `LoginPage`.

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Container, Content, Form, Item, Input, Button, Text } from 'native-base';

const LoginPage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Implement login logic here
    // Example: You can navigate to the dashboard after successful login
    navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', padding: 20 }}>
        <Form>
          <Item>
            <Input placeholder="Username" value={username} onChangeText={setUsername} />
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <Input placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry value={password} onChangeText={setPassword} />
          </Item>
          <Button block onPress={handleLogin} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

```
App.tsx

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base'; // Import NativeBaseProvider

import LoginPage from './screens/LoginPage';
import DashboardPage from './screens/DashboardPage';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

How to solve this error?